# Leetcode - Longest Common Prefix - Why is my runtime so slow compared to the solution?

Tags: java, string, runtime, time-complexity

Question: Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.

This is a easy question from leetcode and below is my answer VS. the solution answer. The problem is: my answer beats 1.17% of the runtime speed and the solution beats 79.65%. **Why is my code so slow?**

Our code are pretty much similar until we start to manipulate the initial common string. The solution does this by calling indexof and substring function in String class and mine does it by using a findCommon function, which is defined by me.

**Solution:**

```
        public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
            if(strs == null || strs.length == 0)    return "";
            String pre = strs[0];
            int i = 1;
            while(i < strs.length){
                while(strs[i].indexOf(pre) != 0)
                    pre = pre.substring(0,pre.length()-1);
                    i++;
                }
                return pre;
        }
```

This is mine:

```
     public static String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs){
         if(strs == null || strs.length == 0)
            return "";
         String result = strs[0];
         for(int index = 1; index < strs.length; index++)
            result = findCommon(result, strs[index]);   
         return result;
     }

     public static String findCommon(String a, String b){
         String common = ""; 
         for(int index = 0; index < Math.min(a.length(), b.length()); index++)
         {
             if(a.charAt(index) == b.charAt(index))
                 common += a.charAt(index); 
             else 
                 break; 
         }
         return common; 
      }
```

In my opinion, the solution code only looks simpler because the functions are defined in String library. But it doesn't mean they don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how you're building up the prefix string:

```
     String common = ""; 
     for(int index = 0; index < Math.min(a.length(), b.length()); index++)
     {
         if(a.charAt(index) == b.charAt(index))
             common += a.charAt(index); 
         else 
             break; 
     }
     return common;
```

Every time you execute

```
common += a.charAt(index);
```

Java has to create a brand new `String` object formed by tacking a new character onto the end of the existing string `common`. This means that the cost of making a prefix string of length p ends up being O(p<sup>2</sup>). If you have n total strings, then the runtime of your program will be something like O(np<sup>2</sup>).

Contrast this against the reference solution:

```
pre = pre.substring(0,pre.length()-1);
```

In many Java implementations, the act of creating a substring takes time O(1) because the new string can share the underlying character array with the original string (with some indices tweaked to account for the new start index). That means that the cost of working through p prefixes would be O(p) rather than O(p<sup>2</sup>), which could lead to a large increase in performance for longer strings.

Answer (score 0):

I  user trie to solve that problem. You can try to user trie

```
#define MAX 30    //the total number of alphabet is 26, a...z

struct DicTrie{
    bool isTerminal;//是否是单词结束标志
    int  count;     //当前字符串出现次数
    int  branchCount;    //计数当前节点的孩子数
    struct DicTrie *next[MAX ]; //每个节点 最多 有 MAX 个孩子节点 结构体嵌套
};


int insertTrie(struct DicTrie *root ,char *targetString)
{
    if (!targetString) {
        return 0;
    }
    int len = strlen(targetString);
    if (len <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    struct DicTrie *head = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i ++) {
        int res = (int)(targetString[i] - 'a');//当前小写字母对应数字
        if (head->next[res] == NULL) { //如果是空节点
            head->next[res] = (struct DicTrie *)malloc(sizeof(struct DicTrie));//new DicTrie;//则插入新节点元素
            head = head->next[res]; //更新头指针 并初始化
            head->count = 0;        //
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j ++) {
                head->next[j] = NULL;
                head->isTerminal = false;
            }
            head->branchCount = 1;//一个分支
        } else {
            head = head->next[res];
            head->branchCount ++;//分支累计
        }
    }
    head->count ++;//每次插入一个，响应计数都增加1
    head->isTerminal = true;
    return head->count;
}

char* longestCommonPrefix(char** strs, int strsSize) {

    int len = strsSize;
    //边界处理
    if (len == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    if (len == 1) {
        return strs[0];
    }
    //组织字典树
    struct DicTrie *root = NULL;
    root = (struct DicTrie *)malloc(sizeof(struct DicTrie));
    root->count = 0;
    root->branchCount = 0;
    for (int  i = 0; i < MAX; i ++) {
        root->next[i] = NULL; // 空节点
        root->isTerminal = false; //
    }
    //
    for (int i = 0;i < len; i ++) {
        insertTrie(root, strs[i]);
    }
    //
    int preIndex = 0;

    struct DicTrie *head = root;
    bool isFlag = false;
    int i = 0;
    int count = strlen(strs[0]);//任意一字符串都可以 从strs[0]中查即可
    for (preIndex = 0; preIndex< count; preIndex ++) {
        int targetIndex = strs[0][preIndex] - 'a';
        head = head->next[targetIndex];
        if (head->branchCount == len) {
            i ++;//拿到合法前缀的计数
            isFlag = true;
        }
    }
    if (isFlag) {
        preIndex = i;
    } else {
        preIndex = 0;
    }
    strs[0][preIndex] = '\0';
    return  strs[0];
}
```

the  runtime speed  is ok.
[image]